# C# service не могу понять, где здесь утечка памяти

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, wmi

Создал сервис с помощью шаблона, сократил код до минимума, и всё равно за несколько минут сервис уже не 4, а 8 мб занимает и продолжает расти. Вот сам код:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    bool close = false;
    bool alreadySend = false;
    bool firstExecute = true;
    int open_counter = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (open_counter >= 2147483643)
            open_counter = 1;

        ManagementObjectCollection sList = null;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_USBHub");
        sList = searcher.Get();
        sList.Dispose();
        searcher.Dispose();
        open_counter++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

На неиспользуемые переменные не обращайте внимание, просто я удалил часть кода, где они используются.
Может здесь и нет утечек, а память сбросится сама в определенный момент, но я не уверен.

Comment: 8 МБ это мелочь, GC еще не активизировался

Comment: Попробуйте в цикл добавить ```GC.Collect();``` чтобы попросить сборщик прибраться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот тут

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_USBHub");
```

Вы создаете обьект.

А вот тут:

```
searcher.Dispose();
```

Вы говорите GC, что его можно удалить, а не удаляете его. И делаете это в цикле.

Это же C#, а не С++. Тут за Вас удаляет все сборщик мусора, он сам решит когда пора чистить и, приостановив программу, почистит.

Попробуйте подождать и понаблюдать. Особенно в Visual Studio это хорошо видно. Там прям график есть.

С MSDN:

Этот метод используется для закрытия или освобождения неуправляемых ресурсов, таких как файлы, потоки и дескрипторы, хранящиеся экземпляром класса, реализующего этот интерфейс. Согласно Конвенции этот метод используется для всех задач, связанных с освобождением ресурсов, находящихся в объекте, или подготовкой объекта к повторному использованию.

Comment: А, я кажется понял, если использовать оператор using, то не надо самому вызывать Dispose, но в моём случае Dispose нужен, правильно?

Comment: Если метод наследует интерфейс IDisposable, то лучше using - шарп сам вызовет тогда Dispose, а если у Вас свой класс какой-то будет, то придется самому звать Dispose, либо реализовать интерфейс.

Answer (score 8):

Об утечке памяти можно говорить только после продолжительного наблюдения и сравнения снэпшотов состояния памяти. Сборщик мусора в CLR достаточно ленив (говоря строгим языком, его поведение недетерменировано), и если у вас на машине достаточно памяти, то собирать мусор он будет редко. Так что запускайте сервис, берите профайлер и делайте снэпшоты каждый час. А потом смотрите, остались ли в живых какие-то объекты, которые по идее должны были уже удалиться, а так же на их количество (наличие некоторого количества таких объектов нормально).

P.S. Ну и да, используйте лучше `using`:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
using (var sList = searcher.Get())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение по поводу сборщика и как следить за памятью. И за using тоже спасибо, просто на C# не писал до этого.

Comment: @МишаковМаксим не за что.